# Trying to access videos using Google Photos API always returns 403

Tags: google-photos-api

When trying to access video-mediaItems from Google Photos using the format baseUrl+"=dv" (specified in the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/access-media-items#video-base-urls)), I always get a 403 error. Images, on the other hand work just fine (Including thumbails for the videos).

I recall some videos worked yesterday, but today none of them work. I have checked my API Quotas and they are nowhere near full.

A basic google 403 page is returned along with the request:
[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riXoF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am getting same issue, i think it become from google server, and they are will fix soon on our serverside

Comment: I think you're right. It has been working fine today.